# Normal of curve at extremum with respect to some coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis

Suppose we have some curve given by parameterized coordinates $\gamma(t) =  \left[ x_1(t),x_2 (t) , x_3(t) \right]$ in rectangular coordinate's, then prove that when the curve is extremized with respect to one of the coordinates, the normal vector the curve at that point is parallel to the coordinate basis of coordinate which it is extremized with respect to. Eg: if $ \frac{dx_2}{dt}=0$,  then the curve is extremized w.r.t $x_2$ , this should suggest that the normal should be $\hat{x_2}$ direction according to previous claim

My try:

The normal is defined as:

$$ \vec{N} = \frac{\dot{T} }{|\dot{ T} |} = \frac{ \left[\ddot{x_1}, \ddot{x_2}, \ddot{x_3} \right]}{ \sqrt{ \sum_i (\ddot{x_i})^2}}$$

Now I need to prove that $ \vec{N} \times \hat{x_i}=0$ if $ \frac{dx_i}{dt}=0$.. but I am not sure how to introduce proceed further since the assumptions are with first derivative and I have above the second derivative.

---

[Motivation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/646591/acceleration-vector-at-an-extremum)

Comment: Note that your formula for the normal is only true of $\gamma$ is parameterized by arclength.  Also, what you want to prove is only true in 2D, not 3D.

Comment: I'd gladly accept an answer explaining all these points in detail :D @JacobManaker

Comment: Haha, yeah…I started writing one and it turned into a mess of algebra.

Comment: Aha!  Coming back to the problem, I think I see a way to avoid the mess.  _Scribbles frantically…_

Answer (score 1):

#### Part I: Solution in 2-D

If we assume that $\gamma$ is contained in a 2D plane, then we can proceed as follows:

$\gamma$ extremizes in direction $\hat{u}$ at $s_0$ and let $P_u$ be orthogonal projection onto the subspace $\mathbb{R}\hat{u}$, which we identify with $\mathbb{R}$.

Then $s_0$ is an extremum of $P_u\gamma(s)$, and so $$0=\left.\frac{d}{ds}(P_u\gamma(s))\right|_{s=s_0}=P_u\vec{T}(s_0)$$  Thus $\vec{T}(s_0)$ is perpendicular to $\hat{u}$.  Since $\vec{N}(s_0)$ is perpendicular to $\vec{T}(s_0)$, and there are only 2 dimensions, $\vec{N}(s_0)\in\mathbb{R}u$ — that is, parallel (*or antiparallel*) to $\hat{u}$.  (This slight emendation of your question is necessary: maxima are extrema too.)

#### Part II: Your claim is not true in 3-D

Take any curve contained in a 2D plane $\Pi$; say a circle in the $xy$-plane.  Extremize it with respect to some direction $\hat{u}$ that is neither contained in that plane nor perpendicular to it (say, $(0,1,1)$).  Then the normal at the extremal point is contained in $\Pi$, and thus not parallel to $\hat{u}$.

(It's worth noting that if the entire curve is contained in $\Pi$, then we can project $\hat{u}$ into $\Pi$ and recover Part I.  But we only need $\gamma$ locally contained in $\Pi$ around the extremum for this counterexample.)

#### Part III: Technique

Although my solution elides it, you mention in your question another difficulty: we only know about $\vec{T}$.  How can we address its derivative?

The key is <s>arclength parameterization</s> that $\vec{T}$ is a unit vector.  By the definition of an orthogonal projection, for any $s$, $$1=|\vec{T}(s)|^2=|P_u\vec{T}(s)|^2+|(I-P_u)\vec{T}(s)|^2$$  In particular, since $P_u\vec{T}(s_0)=0$  $$1=|(I-P_u)\vec{T}(s_0)|^2$$  This is the largest possible value $|(I-P_u)\vec{T}|^2$ can attain (remember, we're projecting a unit vector).  So $s_0$ is an extremum of $|(I-P_u)\vec{T}|^2$, and its derivative is $0$.

It turns out that this extra property isn't really useful for this problem,* but it's a useful trick to have in your back pocket.

* If $I-P_u$ projects onto a 1-D subspace, then we can drop the norm and square before differentiating.  In that case, we do get an alternate solution to Part I.

Comment: What do you mean when you say $P_u$ is orthogonal projection into subspace $\mathbb{R} \hat{u}$? Is it the orthogonal projectio of tangent vector?

Comment: What's $(I-P_u)$ supposed to be?

Comment: the notation has thrown me off but I feel this has the answer ;D

Comment: My original draft split off the 2D and 3D cases a little differently, and that's a legacy of it.  (Sorry!)  For any $\vec{v}$: $P_u\vec{v}=(\vec{v}\cdot\hat{u})\hat{u}$; $(I-P_u)\vec{v}=\vec{v}-P_u\vec{v}$.

Comment: That makes sense but what does $P_u \gamma$ mean? $\gamma$ is a curve, right? Or are you consider the position vector to it?

Comment: $P_u\gamma(s)=P_u(\gamma(s))$.  $\gamma$ is a curve with an implicit parameterization, so $\gamma(s)$ is a point (equivalently, vector).  $P_u$ is just a matrix.

Comment: Hi @Jacob, please @ me next time, I missed your comment. On coming back, does implciit parameterization mean something of form $f(x_1,f_2..,f_n)=0$ ? If so, the notation is a bit tricky for me to still understand. I'll rereading again though

Comment: @Buraian: No, what I mean is we want to identify curves with their range.  This doesn't exactly work (points have no notion of direction), so the fallback is to consider a curve as well-defined _up to changes in the time coordinate_ (that is, an equivalence class).  But here I change letters whenever I change time coordinates; $\gamma$ is a representative for that equivalence class.